# How to select an item via a dialog in a Sitecore SPEAK application?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-speak-ui

In my SPEAK application, I need to have a text field that will hold a reference to a content item. I want the user to be able to select the item via a standard dialog (like the one you see when you click "insert link" on a General Link field) and the ID of the item to be written to my text field.

Is there a standard way to do this with SPEAK in Sitecore 7.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out my SPEAK module here: Im using a ItemTreeView control, using this control you can allow the user to select a single / multiple Sitecore Items.

https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreDataImporter

If you install the release from GitHub you can see my SPEAK application in Sitecore rocks to replace if its easier to follow an example.

But here is the settings on he ItemTreeView I'm using

ClickFolderMode = 1 (activate)
SelectMode = 1(single item selected)

Refer here https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/components/itemtreeview

You should be able to get the selected item from the controls viewModel then. Something like this.ItemTreeView.viewModel.selectedId can't remember the exact property

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this.